# Verify if user has at least one of required roles to be able to update a record owned by a certain user

Tags: c#, .net, authorization

I have a Microsoft CRM 2016 plugin that checks if the user that triggers an update message has at least one of the required roles, when the updated record is owned by a specific user.

Here's the code:

```
public class CheckIfOwnedByPool : BasePlugin
{
    public CheckIfOwnedByPool(string unsecure, string secure)
        : base(unsecure, secure)
    {

    }


    public override void ExecutePluginLogic(XrmObjects xrmObjects)
    {

        if (xrmObjects.PluginContext.MessageName.ToLower() == "update" && xrmObjects.PluginContext.PreEntityImages.Contains("entity"))
        {

            Guid PoolId = Guid.Empty;
            List<Guid> allowedRoles = new List<Guid>();
            var entity = xrmObjects.PluginContext.PreEntityImages["entity"];

            //retrieve id of "POOL" team and allowed roles GUIDs from plugin step XML config. GUID varies from environment to environment...
            try
            {
                PoolId = new Guid(GetAllNodes("ownerconfig")[0].Attributes["value"].InnerText);
                GetAllNodes("roles")[0].Attributes["value"].InnerText.Split(';').ToList().ForEach(x => allowedRoles.Add(new Guid(x)));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(string.Format("Error deserializing plugin step XML config: {0}", ex.Message));
            }

            if (PoolId == Guid.Empty || allowedRoles.Count == 0)
                return;

            //if entity is owned by team called "POOL"
            if (((EntityReference)entity["ownerid"]).Id == PoolId)
            {
                using (XrmServiceContext ctx = new XrmServiceContext(xrmObjects.Service))
                {
                    //retrieve current user roles
                    var userRoles = ctx.SystemUserRolesSet.Where(x => x.SystemUserId == xrmObjects.PluginContext.InitiatingUserId).ToList();

                    //check if current user has one of required roles
                    if (!userRoles.Any(x => allowedRoles.Any(y => y == x.RoleId.Value)))
                        throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("You do not have access to modify this record. Please see with your supervisor");

                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine and is registered in pre-operation of `Update` of any entity. As observed, if one plugin in pre-operation throws an exception, all the plugin stack is stopped, meaning all other pre/post operation plugins won't execute, which is what I want.

Do you see anything that can go wrong? The only issue is that every update done on an entity owned by "POOL", there will be a retrieve to get the user's role. This could hurt performance, but by how much ?

`BasePlugin` is an abstract class implementing `IPlugin` and `xrmObjects` holds useful members such as the tracing service, the plugin exec. context, etc. `GetAllNodes` is a member of `BasePlugin` which allows for easy access of the XML plugin step config.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> try
> {
>     PoolId = new Guid(GetAllNodes("ownerconfig")[0].Attributes["value"].InnerText);
>     GetAllNodes("roles")[0].Attributes["value"].InnerText.Split(';').ToList().ForEach(x => allowedRoles.Add(new Guid(x)));
> }
> catch (Exception ex)
> {
>     throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(string.Format("Error deserializing plugin step XML config: {0}", ex.Message));
> }
> ```

This is really bad. You are hiding the original exception. If you don't want to pass it as an inner exception at least do `ex.ToString()` to be able to see the stack-trace later if necessary.

As a matter of fact this `try/catch` could be a separate method that gets the `PoolId` from the xml you could then just return the `PoolId` without the helper variable outside this `try/catch` block.

---

> ```
> if (xrmObjects.PluginContext.MessageName.ToLower() == "update" && xrmObjects.PluginContext.PreEntityImages.Contains("entity")) {
> ```

Make the method return if the condition is false to reduce nesting.

---

> ```
> if (PoolId == Guid.Empty || allowedRoles.Count == 0)
>    return;
> ```

and

> ```
> if (!userRoles.Any(x => allowedRoles.Any(y => y == x.RoleId.Value)))
>    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(...)
> ```

I suggest you always use curly braces `{}`. It can prevent a lot of errors.

---

> ```
> if (((EntityReference)entity["ownerid"]).Id == PoolId)
> ```

Same here, return if false.

---

> ```
> using (XrmServiceContext ctx = new XrmServiceContext(xrmObjects.Service))
> ```

and

> ```
> var userRoles =
> ```

Be consistant. Use either `var` or types everywhere.

---

> ```
> var userRoles = ctx.SystemUserRolesSet.Where(x => x.SystemUserId == xrmObjects.PluginContext.InitiatingUserId).ToList();
>
> //check if current user has one of required roles
> if (!userRoles.Any(x => allowedRoles.Any(y => y == x.RoleId.Value)))
> ```

You can merge it into:

```
var userHasRequiredRole = 
    ctx.SystemUserRolesSet
    .Where(x => x.SystemUserId == xrmObjects.PluginContext.InitiatingUserId)
    .Any(x => allowedRoles.Any(y => y == x.RoleId.Value));
```

so you can remove the comment and simply write:

```
if (!userHasRequiredRole) { throw... }
```

or even shorter:

```
var userHasRequiredRole = 
    ctx.SystemUserRolesSet
    .Any(x => 
        x.SystemUserId == xrmObjects.PluginContext.InitiatingUserId &&
        allowedRoles.Any(y => y == x.RoleId.Value));
```

*although personally I'd use the `Where+Any`, it looks cleaner*